# Prevent Visual Studio Code to use auto-complete on PlainText

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to stop Visual Studio Code to autocomplete words, or to stop inserting snippets when working on a "PlainText" document?

I love VSC, but I use a lot of plain-text to take notes and so on. I don't want VSC to turn a 'sentence' like "I was" into:

```
I <i class="fas fa-car-wash    "></i>
```

just because I pressed [Enter] after the word 'was'.

I can kill the autocomplete in total, but I like it in code files.
I just don't want it when the type is set to plaintext.

Comment: Sometime before 2022 VS Code introduced file type guessing (for syntax coloring etc.) which at least for me also effects new `untitled` files... (making the wrong guess, „helping“ with annoying suggestions again...). If someone has the same problem, `"files.defaultLanguage": "txt"` in your settings.json might help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Look at `language-specific settings`.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings

```
"[plaintext]": {
  "editor.suggest.showSnippets": false,
  "editor.suggest.showWords": false,
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"
},
```

To quickly fix, open a text file in vscode, click on "Plain Text" in the bottom left, then click "Configure 'Plain Text' language based settings..." in the menu that appears. It'll open a .json file in another tab and you can edit the settings there.  (from @JustasidequestNPC comment)

Comment: Great – I wish there was also a setting to disable these useless suggestions in text content of HTML documents (but not for tags, attributes or class names).

Comment: how do you get to these settings? please include in question.

Comment: @niico open a text file in vscode, click on "Plain Text" in the bottom left, then click "Configure 'Plain Text' language based settings..." in the menu that appears. It'll open a .json file in another tab and you can edit the settings there.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false`.

You can also play around with what VSCode can suggest in Settings:

*Ctrl + Shift + P => Preferences: Open Settings (UI) => Text Editor => Suggestions*

Comment: The official docs don't explain what `wordBasedSuggestions` is, or what the possible options are.  Where did you hear about that?

Comment: @JoelB All the possible settings are described both in the VS Code Settings UI (following the path I mentioned above) and in the official docs.

Please check the following links:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 0):

@cryothic: had the very same problem as you asked for.
I was rather successfull with this somewhat simpler addition to settings.json;
no more annoying test suggestions since.

```
"[plaintext]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false,
```

Comment: Setting false shows a warning: `Incorrect type. Expected "object".`

Comment: @Matthias You should use```"editor.quickSuggestions": { "other": "off", "comments": "off", "strings": "off" } ```