# How can I turn off auto-complete for .txt files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a .txt file in VS Code. I use it for typing in plain text.

It suggests auto-completion. I want to keep auto-completion on for other files, such as Python file.

I want to turn of auto-completion suggestions for only .txt files in VS Code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make a language-specific setting like this (in your `settings.json`):

```
"[plaintext]": {
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,      // or "off"
    "comments": false,   // or "off"
    "strings": false     // or "off"
  }
}
```

Other options are `"inline"`, `"on"` or `true`.

So you shouldn't get the suggestions automaticallyin a `.txt` file, you can still trigger them manually if you want with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

[Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689215/836330 for other plaintext settings you may want to modify.]

Comment: Helpful, thanks. On Mac, I found the settings code in /Users/davemohr/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json

Comment: If one wishes to avoid opening the JSON file, you can get the same effect doing Ctrl-Shift-P -> Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings -> Plain Text (plaintext) -> Suggestions -> Quick Suggestions -> other -> set to off